# Web view from flutter not allowing Download the file and Upload the file

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, android-studio

I'm currently utilizing a Flutter web view for a .NET project, and everything is functioning well except for the download and upload functionalities for files or images.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
I added these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.
```

Comment: Which API level are you targeting in Android?

Comment: @tomerpacific  I am not using any API right now, Except the project I am trying to keep in web view is in .net.

Comment: Since you have an Android variant of your application, there is a build.gradle file with the compileSdk and targetSdk API levels.

Comment: Okay got it, Its compileSdk.

 compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

Comment: `with the compileSdk and targetSdk API levels.` @tomerpacific You mean: `with the compileSdk and targetSdk SDK versions` i think as it is not `compileApi and targetApi`